# Plot complex inequalities $|z^2| > Im(z)^2$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I need to draw the set of all complex numbers, which satisfy the following inequality:

$|z^2| > Im(z)^2$

This is what I've already done:

$|z^2| > Im(z)^2$ 
$|z|^2 > Im(z)^2$ - use $z = a + ib$
$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}^2 > b^2$ 
$a^2 + b^2 > b^2$ 
$a^2 > 0$ 
$a \neq 0$

Is it correct, that the inequality describes the set of all complex numbers except the ones without a real-value - plotted everything except the imaginary axis?

Comment: Yes, except that you mean the *imaginary* axis not the 'complex' one. Another way to see this is that $|z^2| = |z|^2 = (\Re z)^2 + (\Im z)^2$, so the equality fails iff $\Re z = 0$.

Comment: @Travis Right, that's a nice way to imagine it and I made a mistake with the *complex* / *imaginary*-axis. Thank you really much.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.